# Youtube data API refusing my server side requests

Tags: heroku, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm developing an application that uses the Youtube Data API from the server (with node.js) so I have my server side credential key already set up but when I try to get data is always refusing my requests with this message.

```
Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.
```

I've my app hosted in Heroku with the add-on Quote Guard Static that gives me two static IP's that I have whitelisted in the Credentials section of the google developers console. I also have the app hosted in modulus.io and whitelisted the IP range 54.0.0.0/8 that is what they gave me for their AWS region... Any of both deployments are working only in my local machine with my home external IP whitelisted.

The funny thing is that yesterday 15 minutes approximately after I whitelisted the 54.0.0.0/8 range, the app API started working in my Heroku host, but today it stopped again (this might be because it has changed to another IP inside their AWS region or something...).

Is there any way to check what IP is doing the requests to the Youtube data api? I can see in the developers console the request reaching the API and been rejected as "errors" at least I know that their are getting the requests...

Any ideas??

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Partially solved. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple service I found that returns your public IP:

http://api.ipify.org?format=json

You could add a route to your application that you can hit from your browser. The route handler then makes a request to this service and returns the result. You could then periodically check what your app's actual public IP is and adjust whitelist accordingly.

```
// Example express + request
app.get('/ip', function(req, res) {
  request({ uri: 'http://api.ipify.org?format=json' }, function(err, response, body) {
    res.send(body);
  });
});
```

Comment: We have already solved this problem in modulus, the application was deployed by joyent servers instead of amazon aws. I changed it and works fine with this IP range 54.0.0.0/8. Anyway thanks for your help, I'm going to save that service for another occasion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the app hosted in Modulus.io is solved now. The app was running by default in Joyent servers but I changed it to the Amazon AWS region and with the IP range 54.0.0.0/8 whitelisted google is accepting all my requests to the API.

Nevertheless, the app in heroku still not working but as is working in one service I'm going to stop investigating in the other one.